# regex substitution in visual studio 2015

Tags: regex, visual-studio

It seems easy but I am not managed to do so.

`smartPtr(className)` => `smartPtr<className>`

Comment: it's working fine for me !!!

Comment: Use a literal string substitution, deactivate regex mode.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew need to do the replacement in the entire solution. It has more than 100 classes which are wrapped with smartPtr()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, enable the search and replace regex mode to use a regex based search and replace first.

Then, you need to escape the parentheses to match literal `(` and `)`, and use `[^)]+` to match 1+ characters other than `)` instead of the `className` (or `\w+` to match 1+ letters/digits/`_`) wrapped with a capturing group (a pair of unescaped parentheses):

```
smartPtr\(([^)]+)\)
```

or

```
smartPtr\((\w+)\)
```

and replace with `smartPtr<$1>`.

See a [.NET regex demo online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=smartPtr%5C%28%28%5Cw%2B%29%5C%29&i=smartPtr%28className%29&r=smartPtr%3C%241%3E).

**NOTE**: To match `smartPtr()` as a whole word, you may prepend the pattern with a word boundary, `\bsmartPtr\((\w+)\)`, or even a whitespace boundary, `(?<!\S)smartPtr\((\w+)\)`.

Comment: className is a generic term. I have to replace smartPtr(classA), smartPtr(classB) and etc. in the solution